# Change y-axis using autoplot from survMisc package

Tags: r, plot, survival-analysis

I'm using the autoplot function from the survMisc package to draw a survival curve and number at risk table with this function:

```
autoplot(autoplot(survfit((Surv(deathcens.allograft.surv.years.to5y, deathcens.allograft.surv.cens.to5y) ~ AT.interval.10min ), data =  ETdata), censSize=0, type="CI", legTitle = NULL, legLabs=c("<35min", "35-44 min", "45-54 min", ">=55min"), ylim=c(0.4, 1.0), yLab="death-censored graft survival", xLab="Time after transplantation (years)", pVal=TRUE, pY=0.96, pX=0.80)
```

Unfortunately, I do not succeed in altering the y-axis to 0.4-1.0
I have tried several options:

(i) adding *+ ggplot2::scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, 1))*

```
autoplot(autoplot(survfit((Surv(deathcens.allograft.surv.years.to5y, deathcens.allograft.surv.cens.to5y) ~ AT.interval.10min.3 ), data =  ETdata.ATrange10.200.FU.DBD), censSize=0, type="CI", legTitle = NULL, legLabs=c("<35min", "35-44 min", "45-54 min", ">=55min"), ylim=c(0.4, 1.0), title= "Brain-death donors", yLab="death-censored graft survival", xLab="Time after transplantation (years)", pVal=TRUE, pY=0.96, pX=0.80) + ggplot2::scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, 1)))
```

This returns the error: *Error in autoplot(survfit((Surv(deathcens.allograft.surv.years.to5y, deathcens.allograft.surv.cens.to5y) ~  : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator*

(ii) adding *ylim=c(0.4, 1.0)* to the function

by

```
autoplot(autoplot(survfit((Surv(deathcens.allograft.surv.years.to5y, deathcens.allograft.surv.cens.to5y) ~ AT.interval.10min ), data =  ETdata), censSize=0, type="CI", legTitle = NULL, legLabs=c("<35min", "35-44 min", "45-54 min", ">=55min"), ylim=c(0.4, 1.0), yLab="survival", xLab="Time", pVal=TRUE, pY=0.96, pX=0.80))
```

OR

```
autoplot(autoplot(survfit((Surv(deathcens.allograft.surv.years.to5y, deathcens.allograft.surv.cens.to5y) ~ AT.interval.10min ), data =  ETdata), censSize=0, type="CI", legTitle = NULL, legLabs=c("<35min", "35-44 min", "45-54 min", ">=55min"), yLab="survival", xLab="Time", pVal=TRUE, pY=0.96, pX=0.80) + ylim(c(0.4,1.0)))
```

OR

```
autoplot(autoplot(survfit((Surv(deathcens.allograft.surv.years.to5y, deathcens.allograft.surv.cens.to5y) ~ AT.interval.10min ), data =  ETdata), censSize=0, type="CI", legTitle = NULL, legLabs=c("<35min", "35-44 min", "45-54 min", ">=55min"), yLab="survival", xLab="Time", pVal=TRUE, pY=0.96, pX=0.80)) + ylim(c(0.4,1.0))
```

returns: Error: could not find function "ylim"

(iii) adding * + coord_cartesian(ylim= c(0.4, 1.0))* to the function

```
autoplot(autoplot(survfit((Surv(deathcens.allograft.surv.years.to5y, deathcens.allograft.surv.cens.to5y) ~ AT.interval.10min ), data =  ETdata), censSize=0, type="CI", legTitle = NULL, legLabs=c("<35min", "35-44 min", "45-54 min", ">=55min"), yLab="survival", xLab="Time", pVal=TRUE, pY=0.96, pX=0.80)) + coord_cartesian(ylim= c(0.4, 1.0))
```

Could someone please help me? 
Thank you!

Comment: I succeed by using only the plot function (without the number at risk table) with this formula: > g1 <- autoplot(survfit((Surv(deathcens.allograft.surv.years.to5y, deathcens.allograft.surv.cens.to5y) ~ AT.interval.10min.3 ), data =  ETdata), censSize=0, type="CI", legTitle = NULL, legLabs=c("<35min", "35-44 min", "45-54 min", ">=55min"), title= "Brain-death donors", yLab="survival", xLab="Time", pVal=TRUE, pY=0.96, pX=0.80)$plot
> g1 + ggplot2::scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0.4, 1)). But I also need the number at risk table..